Google search console says my sitemap.xml has errors, but I can’t see them
My sitemap is at "http://www.skyeshepherdhuts.co.uk/sitemap.xml". I’ve stared and stared at it and can not see anything wrong with it. I’ve carried out various checks too. Can anyone help me out? What’s the best online tool I can use to validate a sitemap?
Note: it is possibly served gzipped.

If you view the page source of http://www.skyeshepherdhuts.co.uk/sitemap.xml, you'll see that the XML file is cut off before closing <url> and <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> start tags:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.skyeshepherdhuts.co.uk/</loc>
      <lastmod>2024-12-07</lastmod>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.skyeshepherdhuts.co.uk/welcome</loc>
      <lastmod>2024-12-07</lastmod>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.skyeshepherdhuts.co.uk/booking</loc>
      <lastmod>2024-12-07</lastmod>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.skyeshepherdhuts.co.uk/faq</loc>
      

Add the rest of the file, or minimally delete the incomplete url element and add a closing </urlset>.

There seems to be a reproducible bug in the tool I used to ftp-upload the file to the server. The sizes of the one on the server and the original one I have do not match. Thank you so much for your help.
